# how to set local path in javascript of window.open by using in C#.net

Tags: c#, javascript

i am trying to open the excel which was in local disc D path of my system since i have set this bellow string as such but it was not working in c#.net

```
string strScript = "<script language=JavaScript>window.open('file://D:/Ajman/FrameworkWebUI/Temp/ExcelFileName.xls',null,'width=1,height=1,toolbar=no,top=300,left=700,right=1,  scrollbars=no,locaton=yes,resizable=1');</script>";
```

Comment: You can not access local system's files from javascript .

Answer (score 0):

If the file is at the server location  :

you should use a network based address file and not FILE system mode

e.g. :

```
\\myserver\files\aaa.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing local system's files are not allowed by design from javascript .This is a security measure.

[JavaScript Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security)

However you may want to see [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# why don't you use it to get the file, why use javascript?
You could do something like this:

```
string filepath = Server.MapPath(name of the file);
//The file location must be accessible to the website
```

Then you could use the `File` or `FileInfo` classes to obtain the file

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filepath);

//OR

File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will only be able to access a file location on IE. IF you use any other browser it will not work. I think there is a registry hack to have Firefox do it, but to stay consistent across all browsers you might want to read the contents of the file on the server side and show it using a postback or AJAX.